# How to export android application from eclipse in this format?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, export

Does anyone know how to export a android application in this format? https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEcsC.jpg

All im getting is an apk file(know thats for installing the app on google play) and a file(anyone know what this is for)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An APK file is a binary installation file. If you actually want to install and run your app on an Android device, an APK file is what you want.

If you just want a copy of your Android projecct, copy your entire project directory. No export function is needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

An apk file is for installing anywhere.  Google play or side loading or any other app store.  Its the equivalent of a .exe for Android.  That's what you need.  If you want the other thing, just go to the directory where you saved your files, that's all it is.

Comment: you know what the other file is? The first file is of type APK file, but the second file is of type File

Comment: The keystore used to sign it, if you didn't make one beforehand and created a new one.  If you did have a keystore, what's the name of the file?